# PHP passing model as a function argument

Tags: php, laravel, arguments, laravel-4

I'm using the Laravel Framework and I've got `MyModel`.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class MyModel extends \Eloquent {
//Some stuff goes here
}
```

I have made this function that group the data of an array. **This is working well.**

```
public static function GroupBy($array, $key){  
        $grouped = array();
        foreach($array as $arr){
            if(!array_key_exists($arr->MyModel['id'], $grouped)){$grouped[$arr->MyModel['id']] = array();}
            array_push($grouped[$arr->MyModel['id']], $arr[$key]);
        }
        return $grouped;     
    }
```

**Now I wish to make this function more generic by passing the model by which my grouping is made. In order word I'd like to be able to pass `MyModel['id']` as another argument.** Something like:

```
$by = "MyModel['id']";

public static function GroupBy($by, $array, $key){  
            $grouped = array();
            foreach($array as $arr){
                if(!array_key_exists($arr->$by, $grouped)){$grouped[$arr->$by] = array();}
                array_push($grouped[$arr->$by], $arr[$key]);
            }
            return $grouped;     
        }
```

This last solution doesn't work. It returns me an array with an array containing all the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$arr->{$by}
```

instead of

```
$arr->$by
```

See more info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: I just tried it and the result is the same with or without the `{ }`

Comment: im not sure  but try $by = MyModel['id']; without quotes. What does MYModel['id'] holds?

Comment: I tried without quotes but it throws me a syntax error. 
There's a relationship between `$arr` and `MyModel`: `$arr->belongsto('MyModel'). So I'm accessing `MyModel` and then looking for the `id` key of this object.